# pandas: access i column values corresponding to i index value in other df

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access a column values in one dataframe, lets say `new_df` corresponding to an index i in another df (lets say df1)

new_df is looking something like that:

```
Id          100120  100142  118365  269946  621382
2018-12-31       0       0       0       0       0
2019-01-31       0      40       0       0       0
2019-02-28      16      48       0       0       0
```

and df1:

```
0  100121        high  not_seasonal      trending
1  100140        high  not_seasonal      trending
2  118360        high      seasonal  not_trending
```

I know it can easily be done like the following:

```
for i in df1.index:
    new_df.iloc[:,i].values
```

which returns an array like output of the all the columns contained in the i column of new_df
example for column 1

```
gogo [  0  40  48  ]
```

However, the issue resides in accessing the i column of new df within a function where i is passed as a parameter
example:

```
def timeseriesCVscore(i):
    errors = []
    values = df1.loc[new_df.iloc[:,i]].values 
    .....
```

and

```
def timeseriesCVscore(i):
   
    errors = []
    
    for i in seasonal_profile_df.index:
        values = new_df.iloc[:,i].values
```

both gives the same error:

```
KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Int64Index([40, 48], dtype='int64')
```

My code structure is the following in order to automatically iterate over the i's in new_df

```
for in df1:
    return timeseriesCVscore(i)
```

and get an output of an array containing all the values of the i column.

I can't find a way to work around inside of a fonction, any help would be appreciate

UPDATE: Tryout out inside of the function

```
    for f in seasonal_profile_df.index:
        values = np.where((seasonal_profile_df.index[f] == i), new_df.loc[:,i].values, 0)
```

gives the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0, 0, 16], dtype='int64', name='Id')] are in the [columns]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your code:

```
def timeseriesCVscore(i):
    errors = []
    values = df1.loc[new_df.iloc[:,i]].values
```

in case of i=1, the results of "new_df.iloc[:,1]" are:

```
Id
2018-12-31     0
2019-01-31    40
2019-02-28    48
Name: 100142, dtype: int64
```

so, 0,  40 and  48 were used as labels for df1, as if:

```
df1.loc([0,40,48])
```

But, df1 does not have nither the label 40 nor 48, as you find at the end of the error message

```
The following labels were missing: Int64Index([40, 48], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Hi Nour! yes I understand, therefore how can I access that array of data from the index

Comment: you can access them by your code without modification,if df1 has at labels 40, 48 rows, if df1 has 49 rows